# Prove that if $f$ is differentiable over $(-\infty, +\infty)$, if $f'(c) \neq 0$, then $g(x) = |f(x)|$ is not differentiable at $c$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

I tried to prove the statement thinking that $g$ needs to have the left and the right limit equals at $c$ to be differentiable.

I wrote the limit to determine the derivative as
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$ and then replaced $f$

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{|f(x+h)|-|f(x)|}{h}$$

Now I got stuck a little but later I got a hint: we can write
$$f(x+h) = f(x) +hf'(x)+h\varphi(h)$$

So I did it and I got
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{|f(x) +hf'(x)+h\varphi(h)|-|f(x)|}{h}$$

But now I really don't know how to go on. If I could write
$$|f(x) +hf'(x)+h\varphi(h)|-|f(x)|$$
as
$$|f(x) +hf'(x)+h\varphi(h)-f(x)|$$
it would be done, because I would later simplify the $h$ and put a $-$ to get rid of the absolute value when $h\to 0^-$ (since $h\varphi(h)$ goes to 0 as $h$ goes to 0 - i.e. $f$ is differentiable) and conclude that the limit is equals to $\pm|f(x)|$ as $h\to0^{\pm}$, hence $g$ is not differentiable. But that is wrong because
$$|a|+|b|\geq|a+b|$$ and not only equals.

So, how can I conclude this proof?
Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: Can this be true? What about $f(x)=x$ at $x=1$? Perhaps you need $g(x)=|f(x)-c|$?

Comment: The exam from where I took the statement says exactly that and not to tell if it's true or false, even though you could be right

Comment: Problems with the differentiability of $|f(x)|$ only arise where $f(x)=0$. And there your statement is correct. But only there. Note that elsewhere $|f(x)|=\sigma f(x)$ locally, so differentiability depends only on that of $f$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut ok, but that problem was proposed by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg), so I doubt it's wrong

Comment: Well, it **is** wrong as is. There is the additional condition $f(c)=0$ missing from the statement. Check you copied everything, and if so check with him he wrote everything: one of you didn't. Trust maths, not people. People can err.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut [this](https://i.postimg.cc/R0gt7JHz/Screenshot-2022-11-23-08-57-02-21-e2d5b3f32b79de1d45acd1fad96fbb0f-01.jpg) is the original text, even though it's in Italian

Comment: Italian is close enough to french that I can understand the statement. But I stand by my point.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut no problem, thanks for the support anyway